# dialogflow_v2 error 503 Deadline exceeded

Tags: python, web-services, dialogflow-es

I am working with dialogflow_v2, i am trying to get the responses from my webservice Python bassed, when i try at the console it works, but when i try to get te response from the web app i got

> "ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded"

the code looks something like

```
text="Buenos días";    
text_input= dialogflow_v2.types.TextInput(text=text,language_code='Spanish')    
query_input = dialogflow_v2.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
print query_input    
response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: I highly recommend checking out this thread: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6060, It seems that switching to Python 3.6 from 2.7 is the fix